# Lack of imagination when creating projects

Tags: dataset, statistics, data

Whenever I find a set of data to carry out a project, I end up running out of ideas and don't know how to proceed with the project. I don't know how to proceed or what information to look for. How do you come up with ideas for your data science projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with an efficient Exploratory Data Analysis (EDA). After getting a "feel" of the data, you'll come up with hypotheses and ideas to follow up on. Take a look at this overview on EDA and see how the author comes up with new thoughts as she goes through the data: [A Data Scientist's Essential Guide to Exploratory Data Analysis](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-data-scientists-essential-guide-to-exploratory-data-analysis-25637eee0cf6).

Answer (score 0):

When you come across a dataset, it's beneficial to investigate how others have utilized it. Look into the techniques employed, the outcomes achieved, any identified limitations, and whether any emerging technologies were applied. This exploration can serve as a valuable compass, guiding you toward pursuing your projects.